# I need help with STATS homework about normal distribution

Tags: statistics

The distribution of sale price for new MacBook Air’s is approximately normally distributed with a mean of \$800 and a standard deviation of \$70.

(a) Mr. Bob plans to spend between $700 \text{ and } $850 on a new Apple MacBook Air. What proportion of the available MacBook Airs can Mr. Bob afford?

(b) What is the 90th percentile of computers of this type?

(c) Show that a MacBook Air priced at \$1000 would be considered an outlier using the 1.5 × IQR rule.

For a, I tried doing 850-700=50 and $\frac{50}{800} = \frac{1}{40}$,
for b, I tried $m+(0.5 \times R)/y$
for c, I tried $1.5 \times 700 - 1.5 \times 850$

Comment: $850-700=50$?  $\frac{50}{800}=\frac1{40}$?

Comment: Yeh idk what im doing

Comment: But not hopeless: Parts (a) and (b) can be obtained by standardizing and using printed CDF tables of the standard normal distribution. However, (c) does not not make sense as posed, and requires some additional discussion.

Answer (score 1):

In R, where `pnorm` is a normal CDF and `qnorm` is a normal quantile function (inverse CDF).
[You can also get (close to) these answers by standardizing and using printed normal tables.]

(a)

```
diff(pnorm(c(700,850), 800, 70))
[1] 0.685911
```

(b)

```
qnorm(.9, 800, 70)
[1] 889.7086
```

(c) Technically, a boxplot outlier occurs in a *sample,*
not a population, so there is no proper answer.

As an approximation, one could find the third quartile Q3 and IQR of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 800, \sigma=70),$ then see whether
$1000 > Q3 +1.5(IQR).$ The answer is Yes, as shown below:

```
q3 = qnorm(.75, 800, 70)
q1 = qnorm(.25, 800, 70)
iqr = q3 - q1; 
q1;  q3;  iqr;  q3 + 1.5*iqr
[1] 752.7857   # Q1
[1] 847.2143   # Q3
[1] 94.42857   # IQR
[1] 988.8571   # < 1000
```

If you want to know the *probability* that 1000 is a
boxplot outlier in a sample of size $n = 100$ from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 800, \sigma=70),$ then that
can be approximated by the following simulation
in R. The fifth 'statistic' from `boxplot.stats` is
the the lower limit for upper outliers of a sample
(according to the 1.5 IQR rule).

The answer is 'almost 1'; more precisely 97% of 100,000 such
samples of size $n=100$ would regard 1000 as a boxplot
upper outlier. The answer would be a little different
for samples of different sizes. [About 99% for samples of size $n=10$ and about 98% for samples with $n=1000.$]

The so-called [upper fence](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section1/prc16.htm) averaged about
$958.5 < 1000.$

```
set.seed(925)
uf = replicate(10^5,                  
           boxplot.stats(rnorm(100,800,70))$stats[5])
mean(1000 > uf)
[1] 0.96681
mean(uf)
[1] 958.5347
```