# Need some help with STATS

Tags: statistics

The distribution of sale price for new MacBook Air’s is approximately normally distributed with a mean of \$800 and a standard deviation of \$70.

(a) Mr. Bean plans to spend between 700 and 850 on a new Apple MacBook Air. What proportion of the available MacBook Airs can Mr. Bean afford?

(b) What is the 90th percentile of computers of this type?

(c) Show that a MacBook Air priced at $1000 would be considered an outlier using the 1.5 × IQR rule.

For a, I tried doing 700-850=-50 and -50/800=1/40, for b, I tried (m+(0.5×R)/y) for c, I tried 1.5×700−1.5×850+50

Comment: Do not [repost](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3836865/321264) your questions.

Comment: youre so stubborn

Answer (score 0):

a)

$$\mathbb{P}[700<X<850]=\Phi\Bigg[\frac{850-800}{70}\Bigg]-\Phi\Bigg[\frac{700-800}{70}\Bigg]=$$

$$=\Phi[0.714]-\Phi[-1.429]=0.762-0.077=0.686\approx 68.6\%$$

b), c) can you proceed by yourself? the method is the same

Comment: so for b like a do the same thing but replace the 70 with a 90? and for c, how should I set it up using the 1.5x IQR